# multiple forms in same page Jquery Ajax submit

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, jquery

I am iterating a form in **phtml** page 
how can i Submit or validate the form when i click in the button. 
because when i am iterating the form , the id is the same for all form

i am using Zend Framework , i initiate the Form in my view like this to get different ids for each form

```
<?php
$commentForm = new Application_Form_Comment**($answerId)**;
 echo $commentForm?>
```

and i sent the $answer['answer_id'] to put it in the form id to be like this 
**`<form id="comment_form64623"  method="post" action="">`**

is that the best way ? or there is a way in Jquery to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will say, no its not the good way, attaching ID, like that. Configure zend's form to take the id as a hidden paramter, which at last renders as

```
<form id="comment_form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="answer_id" id="answer_id" value="64623" />
```

Next configure jQuery to change the position of the form to different places and update, like

```
$("form").appendTo($("#newDiv")); //Place the for somewhere else
$("#answer_id").val(newval); //Set a new id for the form
```

Comment: Why do you think is not a good way? is it for security reasons?

Comment: @KJA, because you are allowing redundancy to occur in your page. It absolutely not needed. You can use same form for commenting different entries.

Comment: but the answer id different from form to form , they are not the same

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should change the ID for each form.  The difference between ID's and classes in CSS is that ID's cannot be used more than once, classes can.  If you had forms like `id="form1"` and `id="form2"` then you'd be perfectly find, but having them all be `id="form1"` is going to cause some problems.

To answer your question, jQuery would be perfect to address this issue and it would work like such...

Assuming all of your forms have a similar class (`class="formObject"`), you can run code on all of them at the same time using the following:

```
$(".formObject").each(function() {
    //Do whatever
});
```

Conversely, if you wanted to address an individual form, you should call it by the ID (which remember, should be unique to all other ID's on the page):

```
$("#form1 input[type=submit]").on("click", function() {
    //Do whatever
});
```

Hopefully this addresses your question or at least points you in the right direction.